# Redirect and 'field' keyword issues when retriving objects from database

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset, django-class-based-views

I have 3 models Account,Company, and Products.

Company can have multiple products, Account can have multiple Companies.

```
class Product(Meta):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name='products', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Company(Meta):
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, related_name='account', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I'm using Django 2.0 new url patterns, and I defined the urls:

```
 path('dashboard/', include('accounts.urls',  namespace='accounts')),
```

in accounts urls.py

```
 path('companies/<int:pk>/', AccountCompanyDetailView.as_view(), name='detail_company'),
```

In a CBV I'm trying to get a Product instance, if the Product doesn't exist, check if Company doesn't exist and base on the above results do a redirect.

I overwrite the def `get_object(self)`:

```
class AccountCProduct(DetailView):
 model = Product
    template_name_suffix = '_account_detail'

    def get_object(self):

        company_pk = self.kwargs.get('pk1')
        product_pk = self.kwargs.get('pk2')

        account = self.request.user.account
        if not account:
            raise Http404
        try:
            product = Product.objects.get(company__account=account, company__pk=company_pk, pk=product_pk)
        except Product.DoesNotExist:
            try:
                company = Company.objects.get(account=account, pk=company_pk)
                print(company)
            except Company.DoesNotExist:
                return redirect('accounts')
            print('redirect 1')
            return redirect('accounts:detail_company', pk=company_pk)

        return product
```

If I use it as above (with Company code commented) when a product is wrong there is no error but redirect doesn't happen.

If I un-comment the company part, I receive field error:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'company' into field.
```

`company` is the ForeignKey on the Product Model to the Company Model.

I'm doing the Company lookup after, and not before, Product lookup not to do two lookup(s) if is not necessary.

What I want to achieve, example:

Account has 2 Companies with ids 1 and 2 and Company 1 has Product with id 1

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/companies/1/products/1/
```

will go to the product of Company 1

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/companies/1/products/2/
```

will fail because company 1 doesn't have a Product with id 2 and redirect to company 1 detail page

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/companies/3/products/2/
```

will fail because first doesn't found the product and then doesn't found a Company with id 3 in the account and returns to account dashboard

Comment: Can you add your `Product` model ?

Comment: @OrDuan added the Product Model

Comment: You need to show where this code is. The fact that the non-except path returns an object rather than a response implies that it is inside a get_object method, which is not expected to return a response and will not do anything with it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman overwrite the def get_object(self):

Comment: Well there's your problem. `get_object` must return a model object, not a `response` object.

Comment: @solarissmoke so in this case I just return none, can't do a redirect ?

Comment: You can't do a redirect from the `get_object` method. The logic you are trying to do has to be done in a dispatch method (like `get()`, or `post()`).

Comment: @solarissmoke can you give me an example ?, move the logic to get ? what about in case of a queryset fro ListView ?

Comment: Please post your full view code, including the class declaration, so that we can see how you have set up your view.

Comment: @solarissmoke I added the view full code

Comment: I've updated my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do a redirect from inside the `get_object()` method. That method must return a model object - you cannot return responses from there.

You need to do this logic in the `get()` method instead. I think it's easiest just to replace the whole method:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    company_pk = kwargs.get('pk1')
    product_pk = kwargs.get('pk2')

    account = request.user.account
    if not account:
        raise Http404()
    try:
        self.object = Product.objects.get(company__account=account, company__pk=company_pk, pk=product_pk)
    except Product.DoesNotExist:
        try:
            company = Company.objects.get(account=account, pk=company_pk)
        except Company.DoesNotExist:
            return redirect('accounts')

        return redirect('accounts:detail_company', pk=company_pk)

    context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
    return self.render_to_response(context)
```

Note that you are setting `self.object` directly here, and no longer using `get_object()` at all.

Comment: if I filter only by company pk and not account, the company can exist but in another account, so I need to know if the company is connected with account, otherwise he gives a company of another account/user

Comment: if I use your example (with both account and pk filter) I don't have the error but the redirects don't work, remain on the same page;

Comment: Post your full view code - if the redirects don't take place then there is something else wrong with your view logic.